# Prevent GCC (or LLVM) to erase one of two labels referring to the same location?

Tags: linux, gcc, binary, x86, llvm

I do some binary analysis using `objdump` on compiled binaries using either `GCC` or `LLVM`.

To do this analysis, I rely on labels being preserved by the compiler in the output generated by `objdump`.

Consider the following output from `objdump`:

```
0000000000400517 <.cend.c181>:
  400517:   eb 01                   jmp    40051a <.end.c180>

0000000000400519 <.cslot.c180>:
    ...

000000000040051a <.end.c180>:
  40051a:   ff 45 fc                incl   -0x4(%rbp)
```

Here, since labels `.cend.c181` and `.cstart.180` refer to the same location (`0x400517`), the compiler has chosen to erase `.cstart.180`.

A small snippet of the generated assembly:

```
        #NO_APP                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
        #APP                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
.cend.c181:                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
        #NO_APP                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
        #APP                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
.cstart.c180:                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
        #NO_APP                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
        #APP                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
        jmp     .end.c180                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
        #NO_APP                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
        #APP
```

Observe that `.cend.c181` and `.cstart.c180` refer to same location.

How do I preserve such labels, so that my tools work?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that objdump only prints single label corresponding to line of assembly code and there isn't much you can do about it (see the [relevant code](https://sourceware.org/git/?p=binutils.git;a=blob;f=binutils/objdump.c;hb=5b2e229ad7f6aa90ae3a9a5793c9843f395399df#l2060)). Can you extract all labels from ELF's symtab and then match them against instructions in a separate pass in your tool?

```
$ readelf -s tmp.o

Symbol table '.symtab' contains 7 entries:
   Num:    Value          Size Type    Bind   Vis      Ndx Name
...
     4: 0000000000000000     0 NOTYPE  LOCAL  DEFAULT    1 .cend.c181
     5: 0000000000000000     0 NOTYPE  LOCAL  DEFAULT    1 .cstart.c180
     6: 0000000000000000     0 NOTYPE  GLOBAL DEFAULT  UND .end.c180
```